# Signup / Login global navigation links appearing on Signup / Login page?

Tags: navigation, login, signup-signon

I'm creating a web application and we have two navigation states - public (logged-out) and logged-in. The public view spans across a number of marketing pages, splash, legal, faq, etc. Within the global navigation across those pages is a 'Login' link that invokes an-page login flyout, and a 'Sign Up' button which links to a page containing form for both Signing up and logging in.

Should I remove the 'Login' and Signup' links / button when the user is at that page? Or is it a best practice to include them? I've seen other web applications that both include the buttons as well as remove them completely and have a completely custom signup / login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would remove it from the signup / login page.

Why?

I would assume most users login via the flyout login you provide on every page. Users that are on the combined signup / login page visit this page most likely to sign up. So let them focus on this task and reduce distraction and visual clutter as much as you can.

For the layout I'd suggest a small login section and the bigger part for sign up, probably along with listing the top 3 benefits for the user after sign up.

Comment: I agree with you (focus the user action), although what concerns me is that same logic could apply to almost any other page on a website (remove link 'x' because user is already there). That's the part that I can't quite resolve in terms of removing navigation items.

Comment: Right, that is good practice - do not have a link to the page the user is actually looking at. And that's what a link to signup on the signup page would be. Plus, registered users are usually way more valuable, that's why most sites treat this page/flow with special care.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason to remove them. The link for an "about" page is never removed when you're on it. So why do it with the login / register page?